# SpriteKit transition between scenes without resetting game

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene

How can I transition between scenes without my game resetting because `didMoveToView()` was called and reinitialized all of my instance variables. For example I have a game scene and a shop scene. When I transition from my shop scene to my game, the game resets. Is there a way to prevent this or how do I keep the same state of my game when transitioning between scenes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have lots of options to keep persistent state across your game scenes. I've listed two approaches I've used.

**Option A: Maintain a Reference to the Scene**

When a scene is swapped out for a new one, the scene is often fully removed from memory. If you hold onto a reference for the scene object somewhere else, and present that reference, no data will be lost.

To maintain a reference over time (and present the scene again when needed), I recommend a scene presenter class with a static instance such as the following:

```
class SceneCoordinator {
    static var shared = SceneCoordinator()

    var gameScene : GameScene?
    var shopScene : ShopScene?
}
```

when you initialize a `GameScene`, also register it with your with `SceneCoordinator.shared.gameScene = self`. Then, when transitioning away from another scene, you can present the instance you stored in the coordinator class.

`didMoveToView()` will still be called on the scene when it is presented again. You could move all your initializing code to a separate function, create a new instance var such as `var isInitialized = false`, and only initialize your content if it is false (and set it to true after your initialize).

The issue with this approach is that scene objects are expensive, which means you could build up a large overhead by not allowing scenes to be released.

**Option B: Model Struct**

The better way (which would also allow for easier reinit of a scene after your app closes) would be to create a data model of your game state, and provide a function to create a GameScene from your model object.

This method is more consistent with the Model-View-Controller design pattern, and allows your scenes and data to be a lot more lightweight.

Such as:

```
struct GameModel {
    var coins : Int
}

class GameScene : SKScene {
    var state : GameModel

    convenience init(size: CGSize, state: GameModel) {
        self.state = state
        // set up scene content from state
    }

    // lots of fun game scene logic

    func playerCollectedCoin() {
        state.coins += 1
    }

    func moveToShopScene() {
        // init a new shop scene with the state of this scene
        let shop = ShopScene(size: self.view!.bounds.size, state: self.state)
        (self.view as! SKView).presentScene(scene)
    }
}

class ShopScene : SKScene {
    var state : GameModel

    convenience init(size: CGSize, state: GameModel) {
        self.state = state
        // set up scene content from state
    }

    // lots of fun shop scene logic

    func playerSpentCoins(amount: Int) {
        state.coins -= amount
    }

    func moveToGameScene() {
        // init a new game scene with the updated state of this scene
        let game = GameScene(size: self.view!.size, state: self.state)
        (self.view as! SKView).presentScene(game)
    }
}
```

Comment: What are these convenience inits in this example? Don't you need to have didMoveToView in an SKScene? Also what if you wanted multiple models? Like a Person model, Enemy model, etc. Would your scene have a reference to each? Or would it only have a reference to a GameModel and then your GameModel would have a reference to each one? Trying to understand good design for my future apps.

Comment: didMoveToView() is not required to be overridden in an SKScene subclass. It is often overridden to setup content. But again, it is not required. My Model example here is rather trivial, your Model object would be more complex, including everything you need to reinitialize a scene after it is discarded (including lists of enemy positions, etc). Creating additional model structs would help with keeping things clean. Instead of passing around a struct you could also follow Alessandro's advice and keep a shared instance of your model information.

Comment: A convenience initializer allows you to define a new initializer which calls a designated initializer from it. So here the convenience init(size: model:) would call self.init(size:) and then use the model info to set up the game content.

Comment: What would be the best option given I already have so much model data inside my GameScene right now. I'd have to refactor everything which would be a nightmare.

Comment: If you already have a lot of data in your GameScene, and don't want to lose it, you'll have to maintain a reference to it. I'm expanding part A of my answer to contain more detail on an okay way to do this.

Comment: But when I'm transitioning from my GameScene to my ShopScene, I present the instance of ShopScene stored in my SceneCoordinator class right? But that instance hasn't been initialized yet because I haven't called the didMoveToView() inside my ShopScene yet, so it's going to be nil and crash.

Comment: didMoveToView() does not initialize your scene in the sense of nil versus non-nil. Only calling GameScene(coder:) or GameScene(size:) will do that. didMoveToView() will still get called anytime a scene is presented to screen (anytime it moves into view). It is a good spot to setup your scene's contents, under the assumption that your scene will only be presented a single time. In this situation, you want to present the same scene multiple times, so you need to check within didMoveToView() if you've setup your scene or not (and only set it up if this is it's first time being presented).

Comment: In the code above, the first time you move to( or at app startup even) a ShopScene or a GameScene you'll need to both initialize it, and run setup on it. But subsequent times you will not have to - state will be preserved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118963/discussion-between-brejuro-and-cpimhoff).

Comment: Warning , your first approach is a waste of memory, you make a full copy of your scene to another class, what about if your scene spawn tons of elements?

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano SKScenes are classes, so they are passed by reference semantics, not value (as structs are). So there is no copying taking place. My answer does indicate that Option A does not allow a scene to be cleaned up from memory (which will cause the game to use more).

Comment: I report your words because I dont understand what is your intention:  "..When a scene is swapped out for a new one, the scene is often fully removed from memory.If you hold onto a reference for the scene object somewhere else, and present that reference, no data will be lost...", that's wrong, ALL data will be lost:  after a reference copy modifying data in the second variable also affects the original.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano I'm unsure where you draw the conclusion that sharing a reference will delete "all the data". Im aware sharing the reference will allow modifying the data in multiple places, but that doesn't necessarily lead to data loss. Perhaps you are concerned that because the reference is shared, that the object risks being setup twice (overwriting the original data), but I have addressed this concern in my answer. If you'd like to continue this discussion, perhaps in chat would be a better place?

Comment: Sir, I'm sure. Please read the Apple guide about value and reference type here : https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10 at the paragraph starting with "Copying a reference..", your answer explain a wrong thing. It's not my opinion. Unfortunately, there are few things to discuss about this argument. About other things I'll be glad to talk to you: share experience is always a pleasure.

Comment: I'd like to update my answer if I've missed something, but I've yet to see where. Could you explain to me exactly how the shared reference's data gets deleted?

Answer (score 3):

About your question I want to focus your attention to three elements:

- 1) Models
- 2) Shared Instance managers
- 3) Subclassing

1) Instead of repeating everytime in your `SKScene` or `SKNode` the same shared properties (struct, vars or custom classes..) you could create a class that contain your shared properties.

2) It's very comfortable to your project to have some shared instance manager: for example a game manager (shared instance class) that have properties of all managers (shared instance classes) of your project (an example below):

- network manager (check everytime his update method is called if WIFI/3G/LTE are available and store values)
- audio manager (give shared properties about backgroundmusic,effect, volume...
- notification manager (show pop-ups of any type: success, warning,error...)
- file manager (save to file and read from file, clear dirs...)
- etc..

also your game properties model like settings and your game vars.

3) If you need for example a `rootNode` in your scenes (to add elements to pause instead of another, to add object to the same anchored node, to make a background..) you can subclass to a customized `SKScene` that have this properties.

---

Some code to show how could appear your project, starting with a GameManager:

```
class GameManager: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = GameManager()
    var allProducts = Products()
}
```

Your GameScene Class instance can access a single instance of GameManager like this:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    let gameManager = GameManager.sharedInstance
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
       print("the current number of shoes is \(self.gameManager.allProducts.shoes)")
    } 
}
```

Your ShopScene Class instance can access the same single instance of GameManager like this:

```
 class ShopScene: SKScene {
        let gameManager = GameManager.sharedInstance
        override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
            print("the current number of shoes is \(self.gameManager.allProducts.shoes)")
    }  
}
```

Comment: I'm not too great with design patterns, it's kind of hard for me to understand this example. Why does GameManager have a static instance of itself? Wouldn't all the variables in GameManager need to be static then?

Comment: First question: it's the correct syntax in swift 2.x to implement a shared instance ( an instance launched one time only).  Second question: no, you can declare your normal vars, it's the class itself a static instance but his properties can be declare as you wish.